# ngRepeat items and repeat items by a Property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need repeat all items which I have, but I need RE-repeat items by a "quantity" property.

```
$scope.products = [{name: 'Mouse', price: 2, quantity: 3},
                   {name: 'item2', price: 5, quantity: 2}]
```

I need to obtain in final HTML 3(quantity) divs of Mouse item, 2 divs of item2 :

```
<div>
 Mouse<br/>
 Price: $2 <br/>
</div>
<div>
Mouse<br/>
Price: $2 <br/>
</div>
<div>
Mouse<br/>
Price: $2 <br/>
</div> //need Mouse be repeated 3 times by they quantity property
```

Comment: Then bind them three times. `{{price}}{{price}}{{price}}`

Comment: Why not to use ng-repeat twice??? if you are not willing to,  One way is to make two replica of the same data one with mapping as price and then by quantity living together in an array. This way first ng-repeat will iterate through the data having price and then by quantity.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal You never know when the quantity will change.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
    <ul style="color: white">
        <li ng-repeat="product in products">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="t in times(product.quantity) track by $index">{{product.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

in the controller:

```
    $scope.products = [{name: 'Mouse', price: 2, quantity: 3},
               {name: 'item2', price: 5, quantity: 2}];
    $scope.times = function(x) {
        return new Array(x);
    };
```

and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vmjpbj5/)

Comment: Thx that is what i need.

Comment: Glad you find use for it. Don't forget to mark as correct.. if it is of course :)

Answer (score 0):

@neomartin u can show the price depending on number of quantity

> // html

```
<div ng-app>
 <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
    <p>Your Data:</p>
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in products">
        name: {{value.name}} :  Quantity {{value.quantity}} <br/>
              price: {{value.price * value.quantity | currency }}
    </ul>
</div>
```

> // js

```
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.products = [{name: 'Mouse', price: 2, quantity: 3},
               {name: 'item2', price: 5, quantity: 2}]
 }
```

Here is the : [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zttub9z0/1/) i hope this will help

Comment: I need make a ticket Price for every item, a ticket per product, like a market *sry for my bad english